# Find the number of points where the function $f(x)=(x^2-1)|(x+1)(x-2)|+\sin|x|$ is not differentiable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Find the number of points where the function $f(x)=(x^2-1)|(x+1)(x-2)|+\sin|x|$ is not differentiable.

---

My Attempt:
Since the $\sin|x|$ has a non differentiability point at $x=0$ and $(x^2-1)|(x+1)(x-2)|$ has two non differentiability points at $x=-1,x=2$,so i write the number of points where the function $f(x)=(x^2-1)|(x+1)(x-2)|+\sin|x|$ is not differentiable are $1+2=3$ but the answer given in my book is $2$.So i was wrong somewhere.
My Second Attempt:
I redefined $f(x)$ as
$(x^2-1)(x^2-x-2)-\sin x$ when $x<-1$
$-(x^2-1)(x^2-x-2)-\sin x$ when $-1<x<0$
$-(x^2-1)(x^2-x-2)+\sin x$ when $0<x<2$
$(x^2-1)(x^2-x-2)+\sin x$ when $x>2$
I found its derivative $f'(x)$ as
$(x+1)(4x^2-7x+1)-\cos x$ when $x<-1$
$-(x+1)(4x^2-7x+1)-\cos x$ when $-1<x<0$
$-(x+1)(4x^2-7x+1)+\cos x$ when $0<x<2$
$(x+1)(4x^2-7x+1)+\cos x$ when $x>2$

I found $LHD$ at $x=-1$ is not equal to $RHD$ at $x=-1$.
I found $LHD$ at $x=0$ is not equal to $RHD$ at $x=0$.
I found $LHD$ at $x=2$ is not equal to $RHD$ at $x=2$.
So again i am getting three points of non differentiability.I dont know where i have gone wrong.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: The function is differentiable at $x=-1$ because $(x+1)|x+1|$ is differentiable there.